# How can we add the localization for Angular4 web app

Tags: javascript, angular, web, localization, internationalization

How can we add localization support for my angular4 web app?
Is there any other better alternative to get the localized labels and messages for the texts used in the application?

Currently i am thinking of loading the key/value from a service based on the locale and use the keys accordingly. Is it possible though i18 in Angular?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a good library called `ngx-translate/core`. Check it here https://github.com/ngx-translate/core. I've used it for a long time and it provides everything I need. It can also automatically extract the translation keys from HTML templates.

Comment: In this case, all the localization keys will be downloaded to client side is it?
Instead if we request the corresponding JSON according the locale. Is that a better idea?

Comment: Yes. the translations of each language are often stored in a JSON file in the assets folder in the client side. I don't think there's a benefit to what you said. It even slows down your app since it has to wait for the requested JSON file.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But what if that decides while logging in and the complete app will be refreshed and we can request for the corresponding json locale file. Then we don’t have to add those as part of client app instead keep it as a separate files outside. If this is fine then, is there any better solution than this ?

Comment: No worries. Sorry I don't know a better solution.